# Unable to extract large zip file after download from Amazon S3

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, 7zip

A friend has zipped a large csv file (15GB) for me and put it on amazon s3.  Unfortunately, I am unable to extract the zipped csv file once downloaded.  At first,  I thought it was simply corrupted from the download.  I had the friend re-upload now 4 times.

The error that I get is: unsupported commpression method.   When I ran the 7z info command, the compression method on the file said 'Deflate', which seems to be the default.

I'm wondering if its simply a windows file size limitation.  I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2. I also attempted to use Zip2Fix utility to repair the zip but got an "out of memory error".

**details boiled down:**

zip file size : 15GB

inside zip : 1 csv file

os: Windows Server 2008 R2

transfered via S3

error: compression method not supported

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

If your server is on a FAT32 partition (though very unlikely), the max filesize that you can expand is 4Gb. I would highly suggest that your friend re-uploads the file in <4Gb chunks as almost any part of the process could be 32bit-size limited.

Comment: hey thanks for the advice.  past it on to my friend and will report back when have a result